# Photon source for Bell test

Tags: bells-inequality, epr-experiment

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test_experiments#Conduct_of_optical_Bell_test_experiments) tells us that *In practice most actual experiments have used light, assumed to be emitted in the form of particle-like photons (produced by atomic cascade or spontaneous parametric down conversion), rather than the atoms that Bell originally had in mind. The property of interest is, in the best known experiments, the polarisation direction*

What device can actually be used for that source which creates a photon pair with entangled polarisations?

Comment: Hi Juris - I've merged your accounts on this site, but I can't merge in your accounts on other sites. What you will need to do is create a registered account on [math.SE] and on [stats.SE], associate that account with your account here, and ask the moderators on those respective sites to merge your unregistered accounts there into the registered one. You could also email team@stackexchange.com to ask if they would help you with this, but it's possible they may just tell you the same thing. (Also feel free to ask in [chat] if you need help.)

Comment: TO expand on @DavidZ's comments, each Stack Exchange site has it's own accounts, but there is a mechanism called "association" which is used to indicate that accounts on different site belong to the same real world person. The Physics.SE moderators have no power over your accounts on other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process used in this kind of source is the spontaneous parametric down conversion (SPDC, see, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion) for details). It is a nonlinear optical process in which from a photon with angular frequency $\omega_0$ you get two photons with frequencies $\omega_1$, $\omega_2 = \omega_0-\omega_1$. These photons are then phase matched and have correlated polarization (either the same or opposite, we speak of type I SPDC and type II SPDC, respectively).

Comment: Thanks! That SPDC name seems a lot more complicated than the actual process. Is it correct if I say that the method is to direct light through a nonlinear crystal and some part of it is split into photon pairs? Must the light source be laser?

Comment: You got the idea right. Lasers are used as light source, because for nonlinear optical processes large intensities are required. And lasers are the only source that can achieve that.